# Dollar sign in the password causes an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was trying to connect my database using PDO, and this code below works fine:

```
<?php
    $koneksi = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tggamin1_ucp", "tggamin1_tgforum", "ppp");
    function go($location, $alert)
    {
        echo "<script>window.alert('" . $alert . "')</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=".$location."\"><center>";
        return 1;
    }
```

When I change the database details to this, it doesn't work:

```
$koneksi = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tgnew_datab", "pppp", "gofahkur$lvz123");
```

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'tguzer'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)' in
>   /home/tggamin1/public_html/ucpp/koneksi.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/tggamin1/public_html/ucpp/koneksi.php(2):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'tguzer', 'gofahkur') #1
>   /home/tggamin1/public_html/ucpp/profile.php(4):
>   include('/home/tggamin1/...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/tggamin1/public_html/ucpp/koneksi.php on line 2

The database details are all right.

Comment: `Access denied for user 'tguzer'@'localhost'` double check your username / password

Comment: `Access denied for user 'tguzer'@'localhost'` - Check your access rights for that user account.

Comment: Please don't post your passwords! I edited your post to hide them, but you might change the passwords in your installation!

Comment: Ah, @wmk you removed the piece of code crucial to the problem :P

Comment: @hjpotter92, can you do a roolback? I don't see that option...

Answer (score 8):

Most probably, the `$` in the password:

```
gofahkur$lvz123
```

is to be taken literally. PHP tries to parse that as a variable instead and looks for a variable named:

```
$lvz123
```

Try this as password instead:

```
"gofahkur\$lvz123"
```

or

```
'gofahkur$lvz123'
```

Read more about string types in [PHP here](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: This sounds very likely. Good catch.

Comment: Or wrap the password in single quotes rather than in double quotes

Comment: @hjpotter92 I guessed it and now it shows the full password in the error log as compared before but still the access denied, is there any other possibilities for this? The account details are right though.

Comment: @SalenaFanke Try logging in using the mysql's console client. `mysql -u tguzer -p tgnew_datab` see if that works

Comment: @hjpotter92  I did and it seems like access denied there too. 
This is what i've got as the output

Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'tguzer'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @SalenaFanke Then how can you be sure that the account details are correct?

Comment: @hjpotter92 i could login to phpmyadmin with this details thats how i made it sure it is all correct. Is there any permission issues that has to be set?

Comment: If you have root access to the server, run this command: `select host, user, Password, Password('gofahkur$lvz123')  from mysql.user where user='tguzer'` What is the output?

Comment: @hjpotter92 guess the command is wrong? output is `
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `user,'
`

Comment: @SalenaFanke No, not from bash. I meant root access to mysql server. Connect to mysql first: `mysql -u root -p mysql` and then run the select command above.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Here is the output http://oi66.tinypic.com/11h9hc8.jpg
it is yguzer actually i was trying to hide it but now unfortunately revealed :P

Comment: @SalenaFanke Oh, you can always change the passwords at the actual server. Since you were denied access from the mysql terminal client itself, I think there might be some priviledges issue. Run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` as root user in mysql and try logging in as `yguzer` again.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The output 


`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Tried logging in but failed again as 0 rows are affected.  :?